# Using policyd on CentOS to throttle each account's maximum emails on a per-hour basis

Tags: centos, email-server, policyd

I want to apply per-hour mail limits using policyd in CentOS. I want to restrict each email account on the server to only be able to send out a maximum of 50 mails per hour. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is old, but it may help others that stumble upon it.
Use Quotas!

http://www.policyd.org/content/quotas

Just define a quota linked to your default policy that tracks the sender over a period of 3600 seconds,

```
Track: Sender:user@domain
Period: 3600
```

And then apply a limit to said quota:

```
Type: MessageCount
CounterLimit: 50
```